# Unable to render a variable in Jenkins script that uses single quotes

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have a function below that uses single quotes for the script section since I am going to pass in credentials. I've come across documentation suggesting that single quotes should be used instead of double quotes for security purposes. I'm trying to just echo out a username to see if that value gets used properly but I can't seem to get a value to appear.

```
def my_func(String username) {
 withEnv(["user=abc"]) {
  sh(encoding:'UTF-8', script: '''
    #!/usr/bin/bash
    set +x -e
  
    echo "Username is $user"
''')
}
```

When I look at logs in the console all I see is `"Username is "`. I came across this suggestion of using withEnv since I couldn't directly interpolate `${user}` due to the use of single quotes in the script block. I've tried a couple of things such as escaping with `\$user` which didn't show anything. Alternatively `echo Username is \\"$user\\"` gave `Username is ""`

Answer (score 0):

After some additional testing it seems like two things were causing this error.

One was that I needed to update my `withEnv` variable from `user` to `username`. Is `$user` a reserved variable in Jenkins?

I also needed to update how the quotes were used in the echo command. What is the reasoning behind this because I'm still trying to understand Groovy interpolations.

`echo Username is "$username"`